# Programmatically switching to Landscape mode, and then back to landscape/portrtait mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a single-view app. It can be viewed in portrait and landscape mode.

However, a button on the view should force the interface to be in Landscape-only mode. Another tap of the button would bring it back to landscape/portrait mode.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This will get you app rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 2 controllers (portrait and lanscape) and switch between them without animations.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to switch any mode it is create Custom controller which support only needed orientation and then remove it immediately.

Like this:

```
            UIViewController *mVC = [[CustomController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [mVC release];
```